# How can I make my Arrays sort Alphebetically using Collections.sort()? -Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class U3A4_CDCollection extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private ArrayList<String> strArray;

    public U3A4_CDCollection() {
        initComponents();

    private void btnInitializeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        btnAdd.setEnabled(true);
        btnRemove.setEnabled(true);

        strArray = new ArrayList();
        strArray.add("Calvin Harris - Overdrive(Part 2)");
        strArray.add("DVBBS & Borgeous - TSUNAMI");
        strArray.add("Martin Garrix - Tremor");
        strArray.add("Martin Garrix - Animals");
        strArray.add("Firebeatz - Max Ammo");

        Collections.sort(strArray);
        for(int i = 0; i < strArray.size(); i++){
            this.txtAreaOutput.append("\n" + strArray.get(i));
        }
        btnInitialize.setEnabled(false);        
    }                                             
    private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        strArray.add(this.txtInputName.getText());
        System.out.println(strArray);

        Collections.sort(strArray);
        this.txtAreaOutput.append("\n" + strArray.get(strArray.size()-1));
    }                                      

    private void btnRemoveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        strArray.remove(this.txtInputName.getText());
        String strBadSong = this.txtInputName.getText();
        for (int i = 0; i < strArray.size()-1; i++){                        
            if (strBadSong.equals(strArray.get(i))){
                strArray.remove(this.txtInputName.getText());
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(strArray);
        this.txtAreaOutput.setText(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < strArray.size(); i++){
            this.txtAreaOutput.append("\n" + strArray.get(i));
        }
    }
```

I mainly need help with how to use the Collections.sort() method correctly. Is there something I'm missing or put them in the wrong places? I've tried putting it in different places but I havn't figured it out yet still. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: *What* doesn't work, exactly?

Comment: When i try to run it, the add and remove button don't output the strings in alphabetical order

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Just visit our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page for more information to use this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is when you input a new string from the GUI and click add, the output is not in the right order? I think it is cause by a logical error in your `btnAddActionPerformed()`.
You are doing this:

```
Get the new string from the textfield
Add the new string into ArrayList
Sort the List
Add the last String from the List to the output
```

However, the last string is not the new string.
This is what I think you should do:

```
Get the new string
Add the new string into the list
Sort this list
Clear the txtAreaOutput
Print the whole List into the textAreaOutput again.
```

```
 private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        strArray.add(this.txtInputName.getText());
        System.out.println(strArray);
        Collections.sort(strArray);
        this.txtAreaOutput.setText("");
        for(int i = 0; i < strArray.size(); i++){
            this.txtAreaOutput.append("\n" + strArray.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man that worked! I'm not sure why I thought of doing that for the remove button but not the add button...

Comment: Hey do you mind helping me out with another question?

Comment: Okay, what is it about?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, is there anywhere I can message you if I need some quick help?

Comment: You can put your email on your profile, so that I can contact you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the add method is that you only append the last item of the array to the output text area.  You should be blanking out and repopulating the text area because you don't know where the new entry will be in `strarray` after the array is sorted.